# Question about NIB Files

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder, nib

I read somewhere(I don't remember where) that splitting your UI components into different NIB files (and loading them whenever needed) rather than putting all of them in one NIB file increases performance. Is that true? If so, how big is the trade off?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The trade off depends on your UI. When the app loads a NIB file, it need to load all the contents of this NIB, so spliting it allow you to have only part of your UI on the memory at a time (for example, if you have a screen in a second NIB file, it will only go to memory when it is needed).